# taylor's formula in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as exponential of derivative operator

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I hope this question is not too vague.  There is some relationship between the formal operator $$e^\frac{d}{dx} = 1 + \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \ldots  $$

and taylor's formula.  Is there a precise relationship that can be stated here?

Specifically, I was taught a mnemonic once for taylors formula in multiple dimensions in terms of a similar exponential.  Does anybody know what I am referring to?

Comment: Sure, this is a Taylor series expansion, just in terms of an operator.  In $\mathbb R^n$, you would use $a \cdot \nabla$ for some direction vector $a$.

Comment: Hmm, the log of the Pascal-matrix can be seen as derivative operator. Then in turn its exponential (the pascal-matrix itself) might be th answer to your question (I'm not sure as I'm still not really familiar with the notation/concepts as it occurs in your question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one dimension we have the Maclaurin series 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) 
    &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n \\
    &=& \left.\exp\left(x \frac{d}{dx'}\right)f(x')\right|_{x'=0} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and, more generally, the Taylor series 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) 
    &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n \\
    &=& \left.\exp\left[(x-a) \frac{d}{dx'}\right]f(x')\right|_{x'=a}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Likewise, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f({\bf x}) 
    &=& \left.
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} ({\bf x}\cdot \nabla_{{\bf x'}})^n f({\bf x'})
\right|_{{\bf x'}={\bf 0}} \\
    &=& \left.
\exp({\bf x}\cdot \nabla_{{\bf x'}}) f({\bf x'})
\right|_{{\bf x'}={\bf 0}} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f({\bf x}) 
    &=& \left.
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} [({\bf x}-{\bf a})\cdot \nabla_{{\bf x'}}]^n f({\bf x'})
\right|_{{\bf x'}={\bf a}} \\
    &=& \left.
\exp[({\bf x}-{\bf a}) \cdot \nabla_{{\bf x'}}] f({\bf x'})
\right|_{{\bf x'}={\bf a}}. 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: how do you get around the fact that $(x-a)$ does not commute with $\nabla$?

Comment: @orlandpm: $(x-a)$ does commute with $\nabla_{x'}$! (don't forget to look at the subscript)

Comment: @orlandpm: As Fabian has helpfully indicated, the del operator is with respect to the primed coordinates so $({\bf x}-{\bf a})$ and $\nabla_{{\bf x'}}$ commute.

Comment: Yeah, got it now.  Didn't see what was going on with the $x'$ at first glance